# Managing interrupts from custom hardware

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, xilinx

I am working on a driver for a custom piece of hardware (Xilinx FPGA based) and am having difficulty picking up the interrupt it is sending.  The old system ran uCOS-II and just registered the interrupt ID 94. When I register that interrupt in Linux, it never triggers even though I know the hardware is sending the signal.

Is there something besides calling `register_irq`that I need to do?

Is there a way for me to see all interrupt signals sent to the CPU even if nothing has registered for them?

/proc/interrupts:

```
          CPU0       CPU1
 16:          0          0     GIC-0  43 Level     ttc_clockevent
 17:    9383808   10190941     GIC-0  29 Edge      twd
 20:         68          0     GIC-0  82 Level     xuartps
 21:          0          0     GIC-0  45 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 22:          0          0     GIC-0  46 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 23:          0          0     GIC-0  47 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 24:          0          0     GIC-0  48 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 25:          0          0     GIC-0  49 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 26:          0          0     GIC-0  72 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 27:          0          0     GIC-0  73 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 28:          0          0     GIC-0  74 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 29:          0          0     GIC-0  75 Level     f8003000.ps7-dma
 33:      33759          0     GIC-0  54 Level     eth0
 35:      16184          0     GIC-0  56 Level     mmc0
 36:          0          0     GIC-0  57 Level     cdns-i2c
 37:      15117          0     GIC-0  58 Level     e0006000.spi
 38:          9          0     GIC-0  81 Level     e0007000.spi
 39:        204          0     GIC-0  40 Level     f8007000.devcfg
 40:         43          0     GIC-0  39 Level     f8007100.xadc
 41:          0          0     GIC-0  89 Edge      7c400000.dma
 42:          0          0     GIC-0  88 Edge      7c420000.dma
 94:          0          0  zynq-gpio  48 Level     my_int_handle
IPI1:          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI2:      25906      23777  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI3:         37         17  Function call interrupts
IPI4:          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI5:          0          0  IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:          0          0  completion interrupts
Err:          0
```

Boot Log:

```
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
 * Will now restart
þeboot: Restarting system

U-Boot 2015.07-03600-g7bcb6ed (Dec 22 2015 - 12:24:30 +0200)

Model: Zynq PicoZed SDR2 Board
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  ECC disabled 1 GiB
MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0
Invalid bus 0 (err=-1)
*** Warning - spi_flash_probe() failed, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Model: Zynq PicoZed SDR2 Board
Net:   Gem.e000b000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Device: zynq_sdhci
Manufacturer ID: 3
OEM: 5344
Name: SS08G
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 3.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 7.4 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
reading uEnv.txt
679 bytes read in 10 ms (65.4 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from SD ...
Running uenvcmd ...
Setting clocks
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
reading uImage
3946384 bytes read in 380 ms (9.9 MiB/s)
reading devicetree.dtb
8768 bytes read in 46 ms (185.5 KiB/s)
reading uramdisk.image.gz
** Unable to read file uramdisk.image.gz **
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.9.0
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3946320 Bytes = 3.8 MiB
   Load Address: 00008000
   Entry Point:  00008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02a00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2a00000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 1fffa000, end 1ffff23f ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Linux version 4.9.0 (root@analog) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1) ) #2 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 27 22:37:50 UTC 2018
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
OF: fdt:Machine model: ags,FMC
bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled
cma: Reserved 128 MiB at 0x38000000
Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
percpu: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @ef7d5000 s23744 r8192 d21312 u53248
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 260608
Kernel command line: console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Memory: 900532K/1048576K available (5249K kernel code, 231K rwdata, 1696K rodata, 260K init, 154K bss, 16972K reserved, 131072K cma-reserved, 131072K highmem)
Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xf0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 240 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf0000000   ( 768 MB)
    pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
    modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
      .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0528a24   (5251 kB)
      .init : 0xc0701000 - 0xc0742000   ( 260 kB)
      .data : 0xc0742000 - 0xc077bd80   ( 232 kB)
       .bss : 0xc077bd80 - 0xc07a27b4   ( 155 kB)
Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
        Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
        RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=32, nr_cpu_ids=2
NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
efuse mapped to f0802000
slcr mapped to f0804000
L2C: platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
L2C: DT/platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
L2C-310 full line of zeros enabled for Cortex-A9
L2C-310 ID prefetch enabled, offset 1 lines
L2C-310 dynamic clock gating enabled, standby mode enabled
L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 8 ways, 512 kB
L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x76760001
zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at f0804100
Zynq clock init
clocksource: ttc_clocksource: mask: 0xffff max_cycles: 0xffff, max_idle_ns: 537538477 ns
sched_clock: 16 bits at 54kHz, resolution 18432ns, wraps every 603975816ns
timer #0 at f080c000, irq=16
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop... 1332.01 BogoMIPS (lpj=6660096)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
Setting up static identity map for 0x82c0 - 0x8318
CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
Brought up 2 CPUs
SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (2664.03 BogoMIPS).
CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
devtmpfs: initialized
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
NET: Registered protocol family 16
DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
cpuidle: using governor ladder
hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
media: Linux media interface: v0.10
Linux video capture interface: v2.00
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
clocksource: Switched to clocksource ttc_clocksource
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
jitterentropy: Initialization failed with host not compliant with requirements: 2
bounce: pool size: 64 pages
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-241330
dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma:     DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4 Num_Events-16
e0001000.uart: ttyPS0 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 20, base_baud = 6249999) is a xuartps
àconsole [ttyPS0] enabled
console [ttyPS0] enabled
bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
xdevcfg f8007000.devcfg: ioremap 0xf8007000 to f0871000
[drm] Initialized
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
spidev spi32766.0: buggy DT: spidev listed directly in DT
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1 at drivers/spi/spidev.c:757 spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4
Modules linked in:
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.9.0 #2
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c0015f30>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012914>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0012914>] (show_stack) from [<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack+0x84/0xa4)
[<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack) from [<c0023e48>] (__warn+0xd4/0x100)
[<c0023e48>] (__warn) from [<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4)
[<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe) from [<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe+0x7c/0xa8)
[<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv+0x44/0x8c)
[<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv) from [<c029991c>] (__device_attach+0x9c/0x100)
[<c029991c>] (__device_attach) from [<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device+0x84/0x8c)
[<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device) from [<c0297578>] (device_add+0x380/0x528)
[<c0297578>] (device_add) from [<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device+0x8c/0x130)
[<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device) from [<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master+0x438/0x778)
[<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master) from [<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe+0x2bc/0x384)
[<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe) from [<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe+0x50/0xb0)
[<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach+0xac/0xb0)
[<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach) from [<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x54/0x88)
[<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver+0xe8/0x1f4)
[<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c029a4f4>] (driver_register+0x78/0xf4)
[<c029a4f4>] (driver_register) from [<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall+0x3c/0x16c)
[<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x11c/0x1e8)
[<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c05233a8>] (kernel_init+0x8/0xfc)
[<c05233a8>] (kernel_init) from [<c000f938>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
---[ end trace dd90ee247f61645e ]---
spidev spi32765.0: buggy DT: spidev listed directly in DT
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1 at drivers/spi/spidev.c:757 spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4
Modules linked in:
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W       4.9.0 #2
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c0015f30>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012914>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0012914>] (show_stack) from [<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack+0x84/0xa4)
[<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack) from [<c0023e48>] (__warn+0xd4/0x100)
[<c0023e48>] (__warn) from [<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4)
[<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe) from [<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe+0x7c/0xa8)
[<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv+0x44/0x8c)
[<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv) from [<c029991c>] (__device_attach+0x9c/0x100)
[<c029991c>] (__device_attach) from [<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device+0x84/0x8c)
[<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device) from [<c0297578>] (device_add+0x380/0x528)
[<c0297578>] (device_add) from [<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device+0x8c/0x130)
[<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device) from [<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master+0x438/0x778)
[<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master) from [<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe+0x2bc/0x384)
[<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe) from [<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe+0x50/0xb0)
[<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach+0xac/0xb0)
[<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach) from [<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x54/0x88)
[<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver+0xe8/0x1f4)
[<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c029a4f4>] (driver_register+0x78/0xf4)
[<c029a4f4>] (driver_register) from [<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall+0x3c/0x16c)
[<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x11c/0x1e8)
[<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c05233a8>] (kernel_init+0x8/0xfc)
[<c05233a8>] (kernel_init) from [<c000f938>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
---[ end trace dd90ee247f61645f ]---
spidev spi32765.1: buggy DT: spidev listed directly in DT
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1 at drivers/spi/spidev.c:757 spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4
Modules linked in:
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W       4.9.0 #2
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c0015f30>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012914>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0012914>] (show_stack) from [<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack+0x84/0xa4)
[<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack) from [<c0023e48>] (__warn+0xd4/0x100)
[<c0023e48>] (__warn) from [<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4)
[<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe) from [<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe+0x7c/0xa8)
[<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv+0x44/0x8c)
[<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv) from [<c029991c>] (__device_attach+0x9c/0x100)
[<c029991c>] (__device_attach) from [<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device+0x84/0x8c)
[<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device) from [<c0297578>] (device_add+0x380/0x528)
[<c0297578>] (device_add) from [<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device+0x8c/0x130)
[<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device) from [<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master+0x438/0x778)
[<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master) from [<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe+0x2bc/0x384)
[<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe) from [<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe+0x50/0xb0)
[<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach+0xac/0xb0)
[<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach) from [<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x54/0x88)
[<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver+0xe8/0x1f4)
[<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c029a4f4>] (driver_register+0x78/0xf4)
[<c029a4f4>] (driver_register) from [<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall+0x3c/0x16c)
[<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x11c/0x1e8)
[<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c05233a8>] (kernel_init+0x8/0xfc)
[<c05233a8>] (kernel_init) from [<c000f938>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
---[ end trace dd90ee247f616460 ]---
spidev spi32765.2: buggy DT: spidev listed directly in DT
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1 at drivers/spi/spidev.c:757 spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4
Modules linked in:
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W       4.9.0 #2
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c0015f30>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012914>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0012914>] (show_stack) from [<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack+0x84/0xa4)
[<c01e60b8>] (dump_stack) from [<c0023e48>] (__warn+0xd4/0x100)
[<c0023e48>] (__warn) from [<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x20/0x28)
[<c0023e94>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe+0x178/0x1b4)
[<c02f2d44>] (spidev_probe) from [<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe+0x7c/0xa8)
[<c02f0dfc>] (spi_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv+0x44/0x8c)
[<c0298184>] (bus_for_each_drv) from [<c029991c>] (__device_attach+0x9c/0x100)
[<c029991c>] (__device_attach) from [<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device+0x84/0x8c)
[<c029900c>] (bus_probe_device) from [<c0297578>] (device_add+0x380/0x528)
[<c0297578>] (device_add) from [<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device+0x8c/0x130)
[<c02f0c54>] (spi_add_device) from [<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master+0x438/0x778)
[<c02f25bc>] (spi_register_master) from [<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe+0x2bc/0x384)
[<c02f5250>] (cdns_spi_probe) from [<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe+0x50/0xb0)
[<c029b15c>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f0/0x2a8)
[<c0299b94>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach+0xac/0xb0)
[<c0299cf8>] (__driver_attach) from [<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x54/0x88)
[<c0298220>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver+0xe8/0x1f4)
[<c02991f0>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c029a4f4>] (driver_register+0x78/0xf4)
[<c029a4f4>] (driver_register) from [<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall+0x3c/0x16c)
[<c00097ac>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x11c/0x1e8)
[<c0701d80>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c05233a8>] (kernel_init+0x8/0xfc)
[<c05233a8>] (kernel_init) from [<c000f938>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
---[ end trace dd90ee247f616461 ]---
MACsec IEEE 802.1AE
libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
libphy: mdio_driver_register: xgmiitorgmii
tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
libphy: XEMACPS mii bus: probed
[Firmware Warn]: /amba@0/eth@e000b000/phy@0: Whitelisted compatible string. Please remove
xemacps e000b000.eth: pdev->id -1, baseaddr 0xe000b000, irq 33
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
i2c /dev entries driver
cdns-i2c e0004000.i2c: 400 kHz mmio e0004000 irq 36
usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
Xilinx Zynq CpuIdle Driver started
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
mmc0: SDHCI controller on e0100000.sdhci [e0100000.sdhci] using ADMA
ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
cf_axi_adc 79020000.cf-ad9361-lpc: could not find spi node
OF: /fpga-axi@0/cf-ad9361-dds-core-lpc@79024000: could not find phandle
ERROR: could not get clock /fpga-axi@0/cf-ad9361-dds-core-lpc@79024000:sampl_clk(0)
cf_axi_dds: probe of 79024000.cf-ad9361-dds-core-lpc failed with error -2
NET: Registered protocol family 17
zynq_pm_remap_ocm: no compatible node found for 'xlnx,zynq-ocmc-1.0'
zynq_pm_suspend_init: Unable to map OCM.
Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
ALSA device list:
  No soundcards found.
Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SS08G 7.40 GiB
 mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 260K (c0701000 - c0742000)
This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
random: fast init done
Mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux:  No such file or directory
init: hwclock main process (799) terminated with status 1
Adding 511996k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:511996k SS
  * Setting up X socket directories...                                   [ OK ]
Setting default sampling frequency to 2.1 MSPS
/etc/rcS.d/S99default-sdr: line 3: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device1/in_voltage_sampling_frequency: No such file or directory
Loading default filter
/etc/rcS.d/S99default-sdr: line 7: /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device1/filter_fir_config: No such file or directory
 * STARTDISTCC is set to false in /etc/default/distcc
 * /usr/bin/distccd not starting
 * Starting NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ]
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 *
 * Starting IIO Daemon iiod                                              [ OK ]

Last login: Thu Jan  1 21:40:23 UTC 1970 from 169.254.212.36 on pts/1
Welcome to Linaro 14.04 (GNU/Linux 4.9.0 armv7l)
```

Comment: Can you capture boot log and `$cat /proc/interrupts` for better understandings?

Comment: Are you using a Zynq chip? Otherwise, which SoC is receiving the interrupt? Can you post the devicetree fragment where the interrupt is described?

Comment: I'm using a zynq-7000. I don't have a device tree section defining the interrupt, do I need one?

Comment: Are you aware that irq number passed to register_irq not obligatory will be identical to hwirq line number?

Answer (score 0):

Which driver are you using, your custom driver or Xilinx GPIO?

As I understand you hardcoded Linux IRQ number 94 in `register irq`?

```
94:          0          0  zynq-gpio  48 Level     my_int_handle
```

I would say that you have to declare your GPIO node as interrupt controller in the device tree with appropiate interrupt property, because driver uses that information for interrupt:

```
gpio->irq = platform_get_irq(pdev, 0);
```

I'm not sure of the exact IRQ number mapping.

Device tree node for GPIO controller on Zynq looks like this:

```
gpio@e000a000 {
           #gpio-cells = <2>;
           #interrupt-cells = <2>;
           compatible = "xlnx,zynq-gpio-1.0";
           clocks = <&&clkc 42>;
           gpio-controller;
           interrupt-controller;
           interrupt-parent = <&&intc>;
           interrupts = <0 20 4>;
           interrupt-controller;
           #interrupt-cells = <2>;
           reg = <0xe000a000 0x1000>;
   };
```

If you use hardcoded Linux IRQ number instead of device tree, you can try to find it with `probe_irq_on/off();`